# How can I use the Collections.sort method with 2 parameters in order to sort in ascending order a given list in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I've created a class "Planificator" that will allow me to sort the elements of the list by the end date.

Then I would like to delete the overlapping elements.

Basically my code will help me implement a meeting system.

Two meetings with starting dates in ascending order overlap if the start date of the second meeting is less than or equal to the start date of the first meeting.

I've put in my code what would be my example of an expected output to make the things look clear.

The code works on that example but  I think the way I used Collections.sort is not good because it will not work in every case. I'm getting errors if I'm trying something like this Collections.sort(meetings ,new Compara());.

```
class Meeting implements Comparable<Meeting> {
    private Calendar start, end;

    public Meeting(Calendar start, Calendar end) {
       if (start.compareTo(end) > 0)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid date");
       this.start = start;
       this.end = end;
    }

    public Calendar getStarted() {
       return start;
    }

    public Calendar getEnding() {
       return end;
    }

    public int compareTo(Meeting m) {
       return this.start.compareTo(m.getStarted());
    }

    public String toString() {
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
       return sdf.format(start.getTime()) + " -> " + sdf.format(end.getTime());
    }
}

class Planificator {
    public class Compara implements Comparator<Meeting> {
       @Override
       public int compare(Meeting o1, Meeting o2) {
          return o1.getEnding().compareTo(o2.getEnding());
       }
    }
    public static void planifica(List<Meeting> meetings) {
       Collections.sort(meetings);
        for (int i = 0; i < meetings.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (meetings.get(i).getEnding().compareTo(meetings.get(i + 1).getStarted()) > 0) {
                meetings.remove(i + 1);
                --i;
             }
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       try {
            List<Meeting> l = new ArrayList<>();
            l.add(new Meeting(new GregorianCalendar(1,2,3), new GregorianCalendar(2,2,3)));
            l.add(new Meeting(new GregorianCalendar(1, 2, 3), new GregorianCalendar(5, 2, 3)));
            l.add(new Meeting(new GregorianCalendar(3, 2, 3), new GregorianCalendar(5, 2, 3)));
            Planificator.plan(l);
            System.out.println(l);  // [03/03/0001 12:00:00 -> 03/03/0002 12:00:00, 03/03/0003 12:00:00 -> 03/03/0005 12:00:00]
       } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
             System.out.print(e.getMessage());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Report your error in the Question. And use proper indenting when posting code.

Comment: The [Answer by AminM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62478162/642706) seems correct. But you have other issues too. You are using the terrible class `Calendar` which was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically, its subclass `GregorianCalendar` was replaced by `ZonedDateTime`. Even so, this would be the wrong class. Booking appointments should be done with the time zone kept separate, a `LocalDateTime` and a `ZoneId`. Politicians frequently change the offset used by their zone(s). Make a calendar using the two objects to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Comment: Another tip on booking appointments: Record the start time only (a `LocalDateTime` and a `ZoneId` as discussed in prior Comment), without the end time. Instead of the end, record the length of the appointment as a `Duration` object. From that you can always calculate the ending dynamically. We cannot know now what the ending time will be in the future, because of politicians changing zone offsets. Politicians around the world have shown a proclivity for changing their zone offsets with surprising frequency, and with little or no forewarning. Always expect your zone offset to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that **public class Compara** needs to be a static class for you to be able to instantiate it in **main()** because otherwise the nested class expects to have an associated instance.

You can read more about nested classes and inner classes here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Also its much cleaner to write this simply as:

```
// inverted order or whatever you want
Collection.sort(meetings, (o1, o2) -> o2.getEnding().compareTo(o1.getEnding());
```

Lambdas make this sort of code much cleaner

Comment: I can't use Lambdas because I need to solve it in Java 7.

Comment: not a big problem .. just use your syntax but make the class static

Comment: I've made it but that is not the problem, my solution is getting wrong answers on 7 tests and I don't know why. The tests come from a platform where I need to solve the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't store dates as Calendar. I only use Calendar as a utility to handle Dates. I'd store the date as a java.util.Date but manipulate with Calendar. (Date is just a wrapped long really)
You want your dates to de immutable.. calendar is mutable which causes problems (Date isn't perfect either.. but you're still using the older java)

Comment: I'm using the older java because that's the problem I need to solve. All I need to implement is only the class Planificator , the rest of the code is not written by me.

Answer (score -1):

Collections.sort(meetings, new Compara()),
-- in this way you can optimize your sort Algorithm, I manage to get 67 points...but there are some cases that I don't cover them
-Also you may want to make Abstract the Compara class